# Task.Finally extension, good, bad, or ugly?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, task-parallel-library

I wrote this, and it has helped to avoid the 'Some exception weren't handled' problem. Is there something glaringly wrong with this that I might have missed?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles any exceptions on this task, and executes action on specified scheduler.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="task">The task.</param>
    /// <param name="exceptionHandler">The exception handler.</param>
    /// <param name="finalAction">The final action.</param>
    /// <param name="scheduler">The scheduler.</param>
    public static void Finally(this Task task, Action<Exception> exceptionHandler, 
                                               Action finalAction, TaskScheduler scheduler)
    {
        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if(finalAction != null) finalAction();

            if(t.IsCanceled || !t.IsFaulted || exceptionHandler == null) return;
            var innerException = t.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions.FirstOrDefault();
            exceptionHandler(innerException ?? t.Exception);
        }, scheduler);
    }
```

Comment: PS: I *think* I wrote this. It was a while back, so it may be that I filched it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you've really got here is two extension methods hiding inside one.  Your method is doing the work of both a "finally" and a "catch", and I recommend refactoring it into two methods.  The catch method may look something like this:

Edit: clearly I missed checking the exception type before executing the action, but I'm away from a computer and trying to edit code with my iPhone isn't working too well.

```
public static void Catch<TException>(this Task task, Action<TException> exceptionHandler, 
                                     TaskScheduler scheduler = null) where TException : Exception
{
    if (exceptionHandler == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("exceptionHandler cannot be null");

    task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if(t.IsCanceled || !t.IsFaulted || t.Exception == null) return;
        var innerException = t.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions.FirstOrDefault();
        exceptionHandler(innerException ?? t.Exception);
    }, scheduler ?? TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

Edit: Finally got time to get back to this.  Here's an example of a complete solution:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() => {
                Console.WriteLine("In the Task");
                throw new ArgumentException("Thrown from task");
                //throw new Exception("Thrown from task");
            })
            .Catch<Exception>((e) => Console.WriteLine("Caught Exception {0}", e))
            .Catch<ArgumentException>((ae) => Console.WriteLine("Caught Argument Excetion {0}", ae))
            .Finally(() => Console.WriteLine("in the Finally"));

        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

static class TaskExtensions
{

    public static void Finally(this Task task, Action finalAction, 
                               TaskScheduler scheduler = null)
    {
        if (finalAction == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("finalAction cannot be null");

        task.ContinueWith(t => finalAction(), scheduler ?? TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    public static Task Catch<TException>(this Task task, Action<TException> exceptionHandler,
                                         TaskScheduler scheduler = null) where TException : Exception
    {
        if (exceptionHandler == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("exceptionHandler cannot be null");

        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsCanceled || !t.IsFaulted || t.Exception == null) 
                return;

            var exception =
                t.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions.FirstOrDefault() ?? t.Exception;

            if (exception is TException)
            {
                exceptionHandler((TException) exception);
            }
        }, scheduler ?? TaskScheduler.Default);

        return task;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You're right. I actually realised this since posting this question. I suddenly noticed that I didn't 'need' a catch, and then saw why.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of personal preferences here:

- Allow for no `scheduler` to be passed in and use the default scheduler in that case.
- Allow for no `exceptionHandler` if the caller is certain no exceptions will occur.
- Check that `task` isn't null and throw appropriate exception if it is.
- Check that `t.Exception` isn't `null` before using to get the `innerException`.
- Have the method return the passed in `Task` so it can be fluently chained.

Refinagled code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles any exceptions on this task, and executes action on specified scheduler.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="task">The task.</param>
/// <param name="exceptionHandler">The exception handler.</param>
/// <param name="finalAction">The final action.</param>
/// <param name="scheduler">The scheduler.</param>
/// <returns>The passed-in task</returns>
public static Task Finally(this Task task, Action finalAction, 
                                           Action<Exception> exceptionHandler = null, TaskScheduler scheduler = null)
{
    if (task == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("task");
    if (scheduler == null) scheduler = TaskScheduler.Default;
    task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if(finalAction != null) finalAction();

        if(t.IsCanceled || !t.IsFaulted) return;
        var innerException = t.Exception == null ? null : t.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions.FirstOrDefault();
        if (exceptionHandler != null) exceptionHandler(innerException ?? t.Exception);
    }, scheduler);
    return task;
}
```

That way, you can write simplified calls such as:

```
var t = Task.Factory
    .StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("Started"))
    .Finally(() => Console.WriteLine("Finished"));
```

Comment: Thanks. I omitted two overloads, which cover the no scheduler, no finalAction cases, but not (yet) the no exceptionHandler. Point taken about the exception being null, though unless I'm mistaken, in your rewriting, it will still choke on the following line if it *is* null.

Comment: Well, depends on the code the caller has written in `exceptionHandler` - your null-coalescing operator (`??`) may give `null` but the line itself won't choke.

Comment: OK, fair point.

Comment: Should the default `scheduler` be `TaskScheduler.Default` or `TaskScheduler.Current`? `Task.Factory.StartNew()` uses `Current`, `Task.Run()` `Default`. I'm not sure which one is better in this case.

Comment: How do we summon Stephen Toub here?